# Missing profile pic after repair - Android 7.0

Tags: 7.0-nougat, stock-rom, profiles

Anyone know how to get rid of the blue profile pic circle and replace with my Google one on Android 7?

[image: screenshot showing missing profile pic]

The trick used to be to turn on contact sync on Google plus and clear contacts cache, but I can't see that setting in the latest version of plus!

On my Moto G4+ which I've just had reset (as it went in for a repair).

Comment: I don't know if repair has anything to do with it. My phone has done the same thing for years.

Comment: @EthanZ well it was fine before I sent it for repair ;) I more meant after reset...

Comment: I know when I changed my icon last year it came back for about a day and disappeared again. That might be helpful for anyone looking at this question.

Comment: Dupe of question here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174001 (also unanswered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on Nougat and changing the profile photo in contacts app worked for me

Open **Contacts App - Settings - My Info** and change your profile photo.

Works immediately, no restart needed.

Comment: I really wanted to get the old one back. I'm pretty sure this would work as it's going to be a pretty basic error if changing it doesn't _change_ it ;)

Comment: @IanGrainger When my profile picture gone I tried to change it via **Users - Profile Info - Picture** and there, changing it doesn't change it really :)))

Comment: So now I looked I realised part of the problem is that I didn't realise I could click on the generic profile pic to change it! I managed to get my old pic and put it back on and all is good - it's annoying that it doesn't sync for some reason!? Come on Google!